# can't group the ckk fields

Tags: entities

I am using drupal 6. I can create a group inside of a content type, but I can't see any way of attaching a field to the group. In a different installation of drupal on my computer, I see a box right under the new field name where you can enter a group, but this doesn't show up in this installation. Why would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drag a field under the group. [image]

Fieldgroup is already included in CCK module.

Comment: Fieldgroup is installed and enabled. I think I must have somehow messed up this instalation of drupal because dragging the field under the group doesn't do anything. I was hoping that someone might know what happened.

Comment: You mean you can drag the field under the group but still that field is not under that group after saving? Did you try to run the `update.php`? Do you have `Content Permission` module installed?

Comment: There must have been something messed up with my theme files. I made a copy of clean one and renamed it, and now everything works fine! I'm not sure how I messed things up, I have done this before...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by using the Fieldgroup cck module.